# lib directory could not be found in jcdk home

Tags: javacard

I will start a project about Java card on Eclipse IDE.I follow the instructions [here](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/#0.2.Installation%20steps%7Coutline) and when I set the home location of JCDK , I am getting "lib directory could not be found in JCDK home." error.What can be reason?

Comment: Did you extract contents of JCDK? Normally in the folder, there are 4 ZIP files, and you must extract them. more over, the eclipse-JCDE plugin is compatible with JCDK 2.2.2 only. which version do you use?

Comment: The eclipse require address of the folder that named `java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do` (for windows compatible version) and containing folders named `bin`,  `lib`, `doc`, `api_export_files` and `samples`.

Comment: Tahanks @Abraham . It is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you extract contents of JCDK. Normally in this folder, there are 4 ZIP files, and you must extract them. More over, the *Eclipse-JCDE* plugin is compatible with *JCDK 2.2.2* only (You can use JCDK 2.2.1 with it also, but it is a little tricky)

For the *JCDK 2.2.2* The Eclipse require address of the folder that named _java_card_kit-2_2_2-rr-bin-windows-do_ (for windows compatible version) and containing folders named *bin*, *lib*, *doc*, *api_export_files* and *samples*.